# HTML form Accept/Decline buttons

Tags: html, forms

so I have this HTML form with two buttons that say "Accept" and "Decline."

```
<div class="disclaimerAD top">
    <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="index.html" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" id="id">

<input type="hidden" name="process" value="1" id="process">

<input type="submit" name="accept" id="accept" value="Accept">

<input type="submit" name="decline" id="decline" value="Decline"></form>    </div>


<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="index.html" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" id="id">

<input type="hidden" name="process" value="1" id="process">

<input type="submit" name="accept" id="accept" value="Accept">

<input type="submit" name="decline" id="decline" value="Decline"></form>
```

This isn't my code, I don't know why there's two.

Right now hitting either "Accept" or "Decline" brings the user to "index.html." But I want hitting "Accept" to bring the user to "index.html" and hitting "Decline" to just refresh the page, which is called "5.html". How can I get this to work?

Comment: <a href="5.html" class="btn btn-primray">Decline</a> do this

Comment: @SalmanZafar where would I add this?

Comment: Replace Decline button with href intead of this <input type="submit" name="decline" id="decline" value="Decline"></form>
use this <a href="5.html" class="btn btn-primray">Decline</a>

Comment: @SalmanZafar got it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Decline input field and use a link to 5.html instead. You can get them to look the same with CSS if needed.